# Injecting only function and running it through CreateRemoteThread? c++

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to inject this function:

```
void  doubleValue(int pointer){
    *((int*)pointer) *= 2;
}
```

Into a process via `VirtualAllocEx` & `WriteProcessMemory`:

```
int size = 1024 * 1024 * 4;
HANDLE h = GetCurrentProcess();

void * func = &doubleValue;

int arg = (int)&HP;

DWORD adr = (DWORD)VirtualAllocEx(h, 0, size, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
WriteProcessMemory(h, (LPVOID)adr, func, size, 0);

unsigned long i = 0;
VirtualProtectEx(h, (LPVOID)(adr - size), size * 2, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &i);
HANDLE thread = CreateRemoteThread(h, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)(adr), &arg, 0, NULL);
```

Note:
For testing purposes I'm injecting the function into the same process (`GetCurrentProcess()`).

When injected the line copied is `jmp xxxxxxx` instead of the real function;

```
00660000 - push ebp
00660001 - mov ebp,esp
00660003 - sub esp,000000C0
00660009 - push ebx
0066000A - push esi
0066000B - push edi
0066000C - lea edi,[ebp-000000C0]
00660012 - mov ecx,00000030
00660017 - mov eax,CCCCCCCC
0066001C - repe stosd 
0066001E - mov eax,[ebp+08]
00660021 - mov ecx,[eax]
00660023 - shl ecx,1
00660025 - mov edx,[ebp+08]
00660028 - mov [edx],ecx
0066002A - pop edi
0066002B - pop esi
0066002C - pop ebx
0066002D - mov esp,ebp
0066002F - pop ebp
```

So I got a dump of the function

> \x55\x8B\xEC\x81\xEC\xC0\x00\x00\x00\x53\x56\x57\x8D\xBD\x40\xFF\xFF\xFF\xB9\x30\x00\x00\x00\xB8\xCC\xCC\xCC\xCC\xF3\xAB\x8B\x45\x08\x8B\x08\xD1\xE1\x8B\x55\x08\x89\x0A\x5F\x5E\x5B\x8B\xE5\x5D

And tried to write that instead of the &func's data. but still nothing happened.
Also since I injected into my own process that jump address was perfectly fine and that should have worked too. [Test Only, Im not trying to inject code into my own process]

Images from cheatengine+visualstudio.

adr=00443F5B

http://puu.sh/ghRtv/6b87c44154.png

jmp address:

http://puu.sh/ghRum/a612d67e11.png

No matter how much I change the code I'm either getting `Access violation executing location 0xXXXXXXXX` or literally **nothing happens**.

Edit: I know that i can just writeprocmem -> HP, but thats not the point here.

Comment: Is this for some kind of hack?

Comment: Was reading my Reverse Engineering book when I had this idea. Its just a random concept.

Comment: `VirtualAllocEx` returns a `void*`, not a `DWORD`, just so you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm I can't see what exactly is wrong in your code.

The fact you get a JMP instead of the code of your function is probably due to incremental linking.

You shouldn't need to call VirtualProtect since you already have the right page protection flags.

A possible way to get your function is to set it into another section of your executable and get it at runtime.

Here's a simple example, error checking is minimal:

```
// Test.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//


#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#define SECTION_NAME ".my_func"

// put the function in its dedicated section
#pragma code_seg (push)
#pragma code_seg(SECTION_NAME)
static int foo = 0;
void  doubleValue(int* pointer){
    *pointer *= 2;
}
#pragma code_seg (pop)


typedef struct _tag_SECTION_INFORMATION {
    // virtual address of the section
    void* section_address;
    // raw size of the section
    DWORD section_size;
} SECTION_INFORMATION;

// given the name of a section, gets information from it.
BOOL GetSectionInformation(char* sec_name, SECTION_INFORMATION* sec_info){
    char current_sec_name[IMAGE_SIZEOF_SHORT_NAME];
    BOOL bresult = FALSE;

    HMODULE hMyself = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* pidh = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*)hMyself;
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* pinh = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*)((ULONG_PTR)(hMyself)+pidh->e_lfanew);
    WORD numsec = pinh->FileHeader.NumberOfSections;
    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* pish = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(pinh);
    for (WORD i = 0; i < numsec; ++i){
        memcpy_s(current_sec_name, IMAGE_SIZEOF_SHORT_NAME, &pish->Name, IMAGE_SIZEOF_SHORT_NAME);
        if (memcmp(SECTION_NAME, current_sec_name, IMAGE_SIZEOF_SHORT_NAME) == 0)
        {
            sec_info->section_address = (void*)((ULONG_PTR)hMyself + pish->VirtualAddress);
            sec_info->section_size = pish->SizeOfRawData;
            bresult = TRUE;
            break;
        }

        pish++;
    }

    return bresult;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SECTION_INFORMATION sec_info;

    // force compiler to not optimize away the function.
    printf("%08lX\n", &doubleValue);

    // get VA and size of section where 'doubleValue' resides.
    if (!GetSectionInformation(SECTION_NAME, &sec_info)) {
        printf("[-] error GetSectionInformation()\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // open this process
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ,
        FALSE,
        GetCurrentProcessId());
    if (!hProcess){
        printf("[-] Error: couldn't open process...\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // allocate page, size is the size of the section where 'doubleValue' is.
    void* page = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, sec_info.section_size, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (!page){
        printf("[-] Error: couldn't allocate remote page.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    DWORD nobw = 0;
    if(!WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, page, sec_info.section_address, sec_info.section_size, &nobw) && nobw < sec_info.section_size){
        printf("[-] Error: couldn't write to page.\n");
        return -1;
    }    

    int i = 42;
    printf("parameter: %i\n", i);

    // Note: you should obviously *not* pass an address from this address space to another process address space.
    // It is fine here to pass the address of 'i' as we are still in the same address space.
    if (!CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)page, &i, 0, NULL)){
        printf("[-] CreateRemoteThread() failed.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    Sleep(1000);

    // should print '84'.
    printf("result: %i\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

**edit** : same code, but in a remote process, injecting the function in calc.exe, calling the doubleValue() function and reading the result from calc.exe:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#define SECTION_NAME ".my_func"

// put the function in its dedicated section
#pragma code_seg (push)
#pragma code_seg(SECTION_NAME)
static int foo = 0;
void  doubleValue(int* pointer){
    *pointer *= 2;
}
#pragma code_seg (pop)


typedef struct _tag_SECTION_INFORMATION {
    // virtual address of the section
    void* section_address;
    // raw size of the section
    DWORD section_size;
} SECTION_INFORMATION;

// given the name of a section, gets information from it.
BOOL GetSectionInformation(char* sec_name, SECTION_INFORMATION* sec_info){
    char current_sec_name[IMAGE_SIZEOF_SHORT_NAME];
    BOOL bresult = FALSE;

    HMODULE hMyself = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* pidh = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*)hMyself;
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* pinh = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*)((ULONG_PTR)(hMyself)+pidh->e_lfanew);
    WORD numsec = pinh->FileHeader.NumberOfSections;
    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* pish = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(pinh);
    for (WORD i = 0; i < numsec; ++i){
        memcpy_s(current_sec_name, IMAGE_SIZEOF_SHORT_NAME, &pish->Name, IMAGE_SIZEOF_SHORT_NAME);
        if (memcmp(SECTION_NAME, current_sec_name, IMAGE_SIZEOF_SHORT_NAME) == 0)
        {
            sec_info->section_address = (void*)((ULONG_PTR)hMyself + pish->VirtualAddress);
            sec_info->section_size = pish->SizeOfRawData;
            bresult = TRUE;
            break;
        }

        pish++;
    }

    return bresult;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SECTION_INFORMATION sec_info;

    // force compiler to not optimize away the function.
    printf("%08lX\n", &doubleValue);

    // get VA and size of section where 'doubleValue' resides.
    if (!GetSectionInformation(SECTION_NAME, &sec_info)) {
        printf("[-] error GetSectionInformation()\n");
        return -1;
    }

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };
    STARTUPINFO si = { 0 };
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    if (!CreateProcessW(L"c:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)){
        printf("[-] Error: couldn't create process.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // open this process
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ,
        FALSE,
        pi.dwProcessId);
    if (!hProcess){
        printf("[-] Error: couldn't open process...\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // allocate page for function code, size is the size of the section where 'doubleValue' is.
    void* page_function = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, sec_info.section_size, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (!page_function){
        printf("[-] Error: couldn't allocate remote page for function code.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // write function code to remote process.
    DWORD nobw = 0;
    if (!WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, page_function, sec_info.section_address, sec_info.section_size, &nobw) && nobw < sec_info.section_size){
        printf("[-] Error: couldn't write to code page.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // page for result
    void* page_result = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, 0x1000, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (!page_result){
        printf("[-] Error: couldn't allocate remote page for result.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int i = 42;
    printf("parameter: %i\n", i);
    // write parameter to remote process.
    nobw = 0;
    if (!WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, page_result, &i, sizeof(i), &nobw) && nobw < sizeof(i)){
        printf("[-] Error: couldn't write to result page.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // call remote doubleValue() function, passing the address where the argument lies (42)
    if (!CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)page_function, page_result, 0, NULL)){
        printf("[-] CreateRemoteThread() failed.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    Sleep(1000);

    // now read result in remote process, should be: 84.
    DWORD nobr;
    if (!ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, page_result, &i, sizeof(i), &nobr)){
        printf("[-] ReadProcessMemory failed.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // should print '84'.
    printf("result: %i\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, altough i still dont know what i was doing wrong i will be comparing both and eventually find it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is just as wrong. In both question and this answer, casting to LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE doesn't make that thing actually be LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE. Read the docs to see what needs to be passed.